# Edit a document in array if it exists, otherwise push to array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have the following model:

```
var asdSchema = new Schema({
  ratings: [{
     item: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Items' },
     rating: Number,
     date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
  }]
});
```

I have an `findByIdAndUpdate` pushing to an array, however, what would be a good method of updating a rating if an item ID already exists?

```
{ $push: { ratings: { item: item, rating: rating }} }
```

Basically need to upsert for ONLY the `item` field.

EDIT: Current setup checks to see if the rating exists, if it does, it does the following:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: userId, 'ratings.item': item },
    { '$set': { 'ratings.$.rating': rating } },
    ...
```

otherwise pushes new rating to ratings array. Could be quicker I think...